# Equality check involving constexpr instance

Tags: c++, equality, constexpr

I added the following member in my class:

```
constexpr static folly::Unit nullUnit {};
```

Here is the link to folly::Unit :

https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/Unit.h

Depending on a flag, I would return either folly::unit or the nullUnit:

```
                  if (mutate_resp->processed()) {
                      LOG(INFO) << "check returns folly::unit";
                      return folly::unit;
                  }
                  LOG(INFO) << "check returns nullUnit";
                  return nullUnit;
```

I perform equality check like this:

```
if (ret == folly::unit) return true;
return false;
```

However, it seems the comparison is always true even though I saw the following in output:

```
I0608 22:43:37.729920 18225 raw-async-table.cc:132] check returns folly::unit
I0608 22:43:37.731446 18225 raw-async-table.cc:135] check returns nullUnit
```

Any hint is appreciated

Comment: Your ````==```` operator always returns true. Why would you expect it to ever be false ?

Comment: This `Unit` type is more or less a `void` that can be instantiated. An instance therefore represents the *absence of a value,* and it's defined that all `Unit` objects are equal to each other. It seems that you are under the impression that `Unit` is a "symbol" type, which is not what the comments in the linked file indicate at all.

Comment: After reading Unit.h , I came to the same understanding :-)

Answer (score 3):

Folly has this:

```
constexpr Unit unit {};
```

And you have this:

```
constexpr static folly::Unit nullUnit {};
```

It makes sense that these are the same.  Moreover, Folly has this:

```
bool operator==(const Unit& /*other*/) const { return true; }
```

So clearly any Unit is going to compare equal to any other.